# Why does my websocket server accept only 1 connection

Tags: python, websocket, python-asyncio

I am building a websocket server (python3.7, [websockets](https://github.com/aaugustin/websockets)) that consumes Kafka messages (python-kafka) and then sends the messages to websocket client. My code is below. It only accepts the first connection. Why?

```
import asyncio
from kafka import KafkaConsumer
import websockets
kafka_consumer = KafkaConsumer(
    'notifications',
    bootstrap_servers=[server],
    auto_offset_reset='earliest',
    enable_auto_commit=True,
    group_id='group2',
    value_deserializer=lambda x: loads(x.decode('utf-8')))

@asyncio.coroutine
async def notification(websocket, path):
    # register(websocket) sends user_event() to websocket
    for msg in kafka_consumer:
        await websocket.send(json.dumps(msg.value))

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(
    websockets.serve(notification, '0.0.0.0', 8081))
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```